# Adding an updated shared native library (.so file) to an Android Studio app leads to an UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I've an android app written in Android Studio 3.0.1 and with compileSdkVersion 26. This app depends on a module written in native code (c++). The native code in the module depends on a third party shared library (.so) file. In the Cmake file this third party library is included using the standard method, e.g:

```
add_library( my-module-lib

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/file1.cpp
             src/main/cpp/file2.cpp )

add_library( libthird_party_library SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( libthird_party_library PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libthird_party_library.so)

target_link_libraries( my-module-lib libthird_party_library )
```

My module is then added as dependency to the main app and the native code is loaded using:

```
System.loadLibrary("my-module-lib");
```

This all works fine, however I need to update the third party library. I thought this was just as simple as replacing the old .so files for the new ones. But this leads to an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libthird_party_library.so.2" not found
                                                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:989)
                                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
```

It should be noted that android now searches for a ".so.2" file instead of a ".so" file. So I would think that for some reason the old one is still included somewhere, and because of name collision the new one is renamed to "*.2". So I tried these things to get rid of it:

### 1) [not working] Delete everything, recompile everything

Just deleting everything, that is:

- the .externalNativeBuild folder for my module
- the build folder for my module
- the build folder for my app

And rebuild everything, that is:

- Build > Clean Project
- Build > Make Module "my module"
- Build > Refresh Linked C++ Projects
- Build > Rebuild Project

But this still leads to the same UnsatisfiedLinkError

### 2) [not working] Changing the name of the .so file

Changing the name of the updated library to *"libthird_party_library_NEW.so"* and changing the cmake file:

```
set_target_properties( libthird_party_library PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libthird_party_library_NEW.so)
```

Same error

### 3) [working, not a good solution] Rename the old ".so" file and include new one

One "solution" which does work is renaming the old ".so" files using *refactor > rename* to something like *"libthird_party_library_OLD.so"* and then copying the new third party libraries using the standard name *"libthird_party_library.so"*. But this is of course not a very nice solution, because the old non needed library will be included in the apk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with linking a versioned shared library in android studio. Similar as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491065/linking-with-versioned-shared-library-in-android-ndk) and as described [here](http://shellblade.net/android-cpp.html).

The problem is that the internal version number of "*libthird_party_library.so*" is actually "*libthird_party_library.so.2*". This can be found by running objdump under linux on the .so file, that is:

```
objdump -p libthird_party_library.so | grep so
```

which outputs:

```
libthird_party_library.so:     file format elf64-little
  NEEDED               libm.so
  NEEDED               libc.so
  NEEDED               libdl.so
  SONAME               libthird_party_library.so.2
  required from libdl.so:
  required from libm.so:
  required from libc.so:
```

Since the file name as seen by android is "*libthird_party_library.so*" and android tries to load "*libthird_party_library.so.2*" it can obviously not find the required library.

### Solution

An obvious solution would be to change the filename to "*libthird_party_library.so.2*", but this doesn't work because android studio only includes libraries ending on .so in the apk (aaargh).

The solution is to change the internal version number to "*libthird_party_library_2.so*", renaming the file to "*libthird_party_library_2.so*" and changing the Cmake file to reflect this change.

1) Changing the internal version number can be done under linux with:

```
rpl -R -e libthird_party_library.so.2 libthird_party_library_2.so libthird_party_library.so
```

Where the first argument is the internal version number, the second the one we need to change it to and the third the filename. MAKE SURE THE LENGTH OF THE OLD INTERNAL VERSION NUMBER IS THE SAME AS THE NEW ONE!!

2) Change the filename to "*libthird_party_library_2.so*" using your favorite tool

3) Change this line in the CMake file to

```
set_target_properties( libthird_party_library PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libthird_party_library_2.so)
```

Hope this helps!